# Galois extension of $\mathbb C$ is also Galois over $\mathbb R$??

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Is any Galois extension of $\mathbb C$ also Galois over $\mathbb R$?

I know if that extension is finite, Then it is true because $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed.

But How about the infinite case?

How do I approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: All Galois extensions are algebraic, so since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, it has no nontrivial Galois extensions, finite or infinite.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks you!